# How do I launch 2 activities in Android Studio one in the foreground and other one in the background?

Tags: android-studio

I have created a simple game called save the rabit. The MainActivity has two separate buttons. One for launching the game and other to launch emotion detection using OpenCV separately. The startgame in mainactivity starts the game using GameView.java activity and camera_button starts the CameraActivity.java file which opens up the camera and detects emotion in real time. What I want to do is start both this activities at the same time after clicking the startgame button but I want the cameraActivity to run only in the background. I just want to calculate the emotion from that activity and display it to the GameView.java file. How do I pass the values from CameraActivity to the Game. I will be thankful for any help or suggestions.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Open Cv is loaded");
        }else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Opencv failed to load");
        }
    }
    private Button camera_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //to keep the screen on
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        camera_button=findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        camera_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            }
        });
    }

    public void startGame(View view) {
        //create an instance of gameview class.
        GameView gameView = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(gameView);
    }
}
```

**GameView.Java**

```
public class GameView extends View {

    Bitmap background, ground, rabbit;

    Rect rectBackground, rectGround;
    Context context;
    Handler handler;
    final long UPDATE_MILLIS = 30;
    Runnable runnable;

    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    Paint textPaint2 = new Paint();
    Paint healthPaint = new Paint();

    float TEXT_SIZE = 100;
    int points = 0;
    int life = 3;
    static int dWidth, dHeight;
    Random random;
    float rabbitX, rabbitY;
    float oldX;
    float oldRabbitX;
    ArrayList<Spike> spikes;
    ArrayList<Explosion> explosions;

    private int level = 1;
    private int spikeCount = 2;
    private boolean canIncreaseLevel = true;



    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
        ground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ground);
        rabbit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pig);
        Display display = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        dWidth = size.x;
        dHeight = size.y;
        rectBackground = new Rect(0, 0, dWidth, dHeight);
        rectGround = new Rect(0, dHeight - ground.getHeight(), dWidth, dHeight);
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // this will basically call the onDraw method for us and the view?? will be redrawn
                invalidate();
            }
        };
        textPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
        textPaint.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        textPaint.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.kenney_blocks));

        textPaint2.setColor(Color.rgb(36, 110, 185));
        textPaint2.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE);
        textPaint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        textPaint2.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.kenney_blocks));

        healthPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        random = new Random();
        // that the rabbit can be drawn horizontally center and on top of ground
        rabbitX = dWidth / 2 - rabbit.getWidth() / 2;
        rabbitY = dHeight - ground.getHeight() - rabbit.getHeight();
        spikes = new ArrayList<>();
        explosions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<spikeCount; i++){
            Spike spike = new Spike(context);
            spikes.add(spike);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, null, rectBackground, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ground, null, rectGround, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(rabbit, rabbitX, rabbitY, null);
        for (int i=0; i<spikes.size(); i++){//minus 1 bola tha,
            canvas.drawBitmap(spikes.get(i).getSpike(spikes.get(i).spikeFrame), spikes.get(i).spikeX, spikes.get(i).spikeY, null);
            spikes.get(i).spikeFrame++;
            if (spikes.get(i).spikeFrame > 2){
                spikes.get(i).spikeFrame = 0;
            }
            spikes.get(i).spikeY += spikes.get(i).spikeVelocity;
            if (spikes.get(i).spikeY + spikes.get(i).getSpikeHeight() >= dHeight - ground.getHeight()){
                points += 10;
                Explosion explosion = new Explosion(context);
                explosion.explosionX = spikes.get(i).spikeX;
                explosion.explosionY = spikes.get(i).spikeY;
                explosions.add(explosion);
                spikes.get(i).resetPosition();
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<spikes.size(); i++){
            if (spikes.get(i).spikeX + spikes.get(i).getSpikeWidth() >= rabbitX
            && spikes.get(i).spikeX <= rabbitX + rabbit.getWidth()
            && spikes.get(i).spikeY + spikes.get(i).getSpikeWidth() >= rabbitY
            && spikes.get(i).spikeY + spikes.get(i).getSpikeWidth() <= rabbitY + rabbit.getHeight()){
                life--;
                spikes.get(i).resetPosition();
                if (life == 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameOver.class);
                    intent.putExtra("points", points);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    ((Activity) context).finish();
                }
            }
        }


        for(int i=0; i<explosions.size(); i++){
            canvas.drawBitmap(explosions.get(i).getExplosion(explosions.get(i).explosionFrame), explosions.get(i).explosionX,
                    explosions.get(i).explosionY, null);
            explosions.get(i).explosionFrame++;
            if (explosions.get(i).explosionFrame > 3){
                explosions.remove(i);
            }
        }

        if(life == 2){
            healthPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if(life == 1){
            healthPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }

        canvas.drawRect(dWidth-200, 30, dWidth-200+60*life, 80, healthPaint);
        String levelText = "Level " + level;
        canvas.drawText(levelText, 20, TEXT_SIZE, textPaint2);
        canvas.drawText(""+points, 20, 2*TEXT_SIZE, textPaint);


        if (points == 1600 && level < 7) {
            increaseLevel(6);
        }
        else if (points == 1200 && level < 7) {
            increaseLevel(5);
        }
        else if (points == 800 && level < 7) {
            increaseLevel(4);
        }
        else if (points == 500 && level < 7) {
            increaseLevel(3);
        }
        else if (points == 300 && level < 7) {
            increaseLevel(2);
        } else if (points == 100 && level < 7) {
            increaseLevel(1);
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, UPDATE_MILLIS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        if (touchY >= rabbitY){
            int action = event.getAction();
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                oldX = event.getX();
                oldRabbitX = rabbitX;
            if( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                float shift = oldX - touchX;
                float newRabbitX = oldRabbitX - shift;
                if (newRabbitX <= 0){
                    rabbitX = 0;
                }
                else if(newRabbitX >= dWidth - rabbit.getWidth())
                    rabbitX = dWidth - rabbit.getWidth();
                else rabbitX = newRabbitX;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void increaseLevel(int lvl) {
        if(lvl == level){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Level is increased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            level++;
            Spike spike = new Spike(context);
            spikes.add(spike);
        }
    }


}
```

**CameraActivity.java**

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{
    private static final String TAG="MainActivity";

    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mGray;
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

    private facialExpressionRecognition facialExpressionRecognition;
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback =new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status){
                case LoaderCallbackInterface
                        .SUCCESS:{
                    Log.i(TAG,"OpenCv Is loaded");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                }
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    private HashMap<String, Integer> emotionCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static final int FRAMES_INTERVAL = 15;
    private int frameCounter = 0;
    private String maxEmotionDuringInterval = "";

    public CameraActivity(){
        Log.i(TAG,"Instantiated new "+this.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA=0;
        // if camera permission is not given it will ask for it on device
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CameraActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        mOpenCvCameraView=(CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.frame_surface);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(1);

        try{
            //input size of model is 48
            int inputSize = 48;
            facialExpressionRecognition = new facialExpressionRecognition(getAssets(), CameraActivity.this, "model300.tflite", inputSize);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            //if load success
            Log.d(TAG,"Opencv initialization is done");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
        else{
            //if not loaded
            Log.d(TAG,"Opencv is not loaded. try again");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_4_0,this,mLoaderCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView !=null){
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mOpenCvCameraView !=null){
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }

    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width ,int height){
        mRgba=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mGray =new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC1);
    }
    public void onCameraViewStopped(){
        mRgba.release();
    }
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){
        frameCounter++;


        mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray=inputFrame.gray();
        Core.flip(mRgba, mRgba, 0);
        mRgba=facialExpressionRecognition.recognizeImage(mRgba);
        float curr_emotion_v = facialExpressionRecognition.curr_emotion_v;
        String curr_emotion_string = facialExpressionRecognition.get_emotion_text(curr_emotion_v);

        if (frameCounter == FRAMES_INTERVAL) {
            frameCounter = 0;
            updateEmotionCount(curr_emotion_string);
            maxEmotionDuringInterval = getMaxEmotion();
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String maxEmotion = getMaxEmotion();
                TextView txtEmotion = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                //txtEmotion.setText(curr_emotion_string);
                txtEmotion.setText(maxEmotionDuringInterval);
            }
        });
        return mRgba;
    }

    private void updateEmotionCount(String emotion) {
        emotionCountMap.put(emotion, emotionCountMap.getOrDefault(emotion, 0) + 1);
    }

    private String getMaxEmotion() {
        // Find the emotion with the maximum count in the HashMap
        int maxCount = 0;
        String maxEmotion = "";
        for (String emotion : emotionCountMap.keySet()) {
            int count = emotionCountMap.get(emotion);
            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                maxEmotion = emotion;
            }
        }
        emotionCountMap.clear();
        return maxEmotion;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"What I want to do is start both this activities at the same time after clicking the startgame button but I want the cameraActivity to run only in the background."_ Sound like `CameraActivity` should be a `Service` instead then. (Assuming you can do any OpenCV stuff without having an actual camera preview on the UI. I'm not familiar with machine vision.) An `Activity` in the background actually doing something just isn't a real concept in Android. Once it loses the foreground it goes through the usual `OnPause()` and eventually `OnDestoy()` cycle.